# SVN post-commit hook makes committing very slow - how to fix?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, hook

I added a post-commit hook to my repository on a Windows 2008 server. So every time something is committed, I cd to the folder of my apps and run *svn update*. This works, but its extremely slow and TortoiseSVN does not finish until the post-commit hook finished. How can I make this faster? One way might be to not cd to any app, but only to the one where a commit took place. How could I figure out, which app got a commit? Some regex and $1? I tried only one app and its still1.5 minutes for a single file, way to long.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would decouple the commit from the update completely, like (AFAIK) continuous integration servers do. Have a cron trigger an update every X minutes on your apps. This way, the commit time will not be impacted at all.

Comment: And if you don't want to poll with cron jobs, you could use a post commit hook to signal some sort of scheduler or message queue. So most of the work is still handled by another process shortly after the commit.

Comment: How would that look like? How would I do that in a batch file?

Comment: You could just use the start command to execute your update command "asynchronously".

Comment: +1 for the "start" command. Perfect solution, as it's very simple.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Subversion hook and take a look at [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org). Jenkins is a continuous build server, but what it does is run a process after a commit is done in Subversion. Normally, this can be a build, but it can also be running a Subversion update on your server.

Jenkins will log everything and notify you (via email, tweet, IM, or even [traffic light](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Traffic+Light+Plugin)) when something goes wrong.

It's easy to see the changes, the history, etc. Plus, it doesn't slow down Subversion.

By the way, I recommend the following process:

- Your server is running from say `C:\inetd\www`.
- Create a new directory called `C:\inetd\www2` and do a `svn export` to that directory.
- Rename `C:\inetd\www2` to `C:\inetd\www`. You might have to bounce your server.

What this does is make sure your server is never running where some files in its directory are at revision 2000 while others are at revision 2001. This way, all of your changes are done at the same time. Plus, you don't have all those `.svn` directories all over the place (although Subversion 1.7 client has improved this quite a bit).